# How can I unit test my python bot using Microsoft bot framework?

Tags: python, unit-testing, azure-devops, python-unittest, botframework

I'm building a bot using python and the Microsoft Bot Framework, running on localhost only. I want to perform unit tests on it, however every info I find is using C# or Javascript and I don't understand how to do this on Python.

PD: I'm also trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline for this on Azure Devops (just in case anyone knows if DevOps has anything that could help with doing these unit tests or something, sorry, I'm very new to this and still learning)

Comment: I suggest googling "python unit tests". There is a lot of information available online for this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes but how do i specifically test a bot? I mean, to test it manually I run python app.py from a terminal in order to get answers from it, but with unit tests I don't know how to automatically start the bot to give answers to my tests by running just the unit tests script

Comment: Usually with unit tests, you call a function with some parameters and verify that the function's result is what you expect. Without more detail, say a code example of a bot, I can't give more details information because I don't know which part you need help with.

Comment: Also, I'm unfamiliar with Microsoft Bot Framework, so I'm trying to give some general tips that hopefully helps.

Comment: I went into a little more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64310567/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-an-aiohttp-request-in-python-bot-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the official  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#run-tests) you can refer to. You can use scripts to install and run various tests in your pipeline.

This [blog](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2018/11/12/run-python-test-with-azure-devops-pipeline/) also introduces run Python test with Azure DevOps pipeline.

In addition , you can try to use [Python Test](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dazfuller.pyunittest-task) extension.

Execute your Python 3 unit tests in Visual Studio Team Services and get your test results and coverage information as part of your build.
The task uses the Python unittest-xml-reporting and coverage.py modules to execute the unit tests using test discovery.

Comment: ok but how do i specifically test a bot? I mean, to test it manually I run python app.py from a terminal in order to get answers from it once its running on localhost, but with unit tests I don't know how to automatically start the bot to give answers to my tests by running just the unit tests script